# How do I make NumberFormatter format a percent number without "reinterpreting" it?

Tags: php, number-formatting, percentage

***Example code:***

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('sv_SE', NumberFormatter::PERCENT);
var_dump($fmt->format(99.99));
```

***Expected output:***

```
string(9) "99,99 %"
```

***Actual output:***

```
string(9) "9 999 %"
```

***Analysis:***

I must be "missing something". I already have the percentage number (ninenty-nine point ninenty-nine) and all I want is to output it appropriately for the given language+locale combination. For example, in the USA, it is "99.99%" with a period for the decimal mark and no space between the percentage number and the percentage sign, and in Sweden, it's "99,99 %" with a comma for the decimal mark and a space between. There are probably numerous other rules in other locales/language which I just haven't encountered yet.

I do *not* want PHP to "further process" the number I'm feeding it in any way. It's already "done". No more processing needed.

I frankly don't even understand why PHP turns it into "9999" when it's clearly given as a float as 99.99...

**Is there some kind of hidden option to turn off this "further processing" of the number?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumberFormatter is assuming the number to be between 0-1 in your case 99.99/100 === 0.9999
therefore you could use it that ways  :

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('sv_SE', NumberFormatter::PERCENT);
var_dump($fmt->format(99.99/100));
```

From reading [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.numberformatter.php) I highly doubt there is any other way.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about this, actually. It seems obvious now, but... I still don't really get why they expect such a number, or why it's not mentioned in the manual, but I "got it working" at least.